# Is my html code for a canvas in a div correct?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put a canvas in a div so I can hide it and show it with a button and be able to resize it, but currently it isn't showing up... which is weird. Is my code correct?

```
<div id="blob"></div>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="blob.js"></script>
  </div>
```

^ it's this part of the code, the other parts are unrelated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Quiz App</title>
</head>
<body>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container2">
      <img name="slide">
    </div> 
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Question</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <div id="startmsgcontainer" class="hide"></div>
        <div id="startmsg">Adventure Into The Human Immune System</div>
        </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start!</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
      <button id="end-btn" class="end-btn btn hide">End (this will close the current tab)</button>
      <button id="try-btn" class="try-btn btn hide">Try again!</button>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="img/uni.png" alt="image">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="blob"></div>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="blob.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div id="particles-js"></div>
  <script src="particles.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="slide.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here's how the canvas is created... I think it's correct? It worked by itself but I'm not so sure with the other things. this is `sketch.js`

```
var blob;

var blobs = [];
var zoom = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  blob = new Blob(0, 0, 64);
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    var x = random(-width, width);
    var y = random(-height, height);
    blobs[i] = new Blob(x, y, 16);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  var newzoom = 64 / blob.r;
  zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.1);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-blob.pos.x, -blob.pos.y);

  for (var i = blobs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    blobs[i].show();
    if (blob.eats(blobs[i])) {
      blobs.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  blob.show();
  blob.update();
}
```

Comment: I don't see canvas element.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar the canvas is created in the ```sketch.js```

Comment: And I couldn't see anywhere you calling a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
```

this only imports a javascript file. Unless that javascript creates a canvas element and you run it then nothing will show up

Comment: well I think it does

Comment: It is recommended to put all script tag near the end of your HTML. If sketch.js is doing something like document.createElement() then you just need to run the javascript.